# How to use wordcount with CDN ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor-wordcount

Why doesn't this work?

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.8/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
    CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('wordcount', '/assets/ckeditor/plugins/wordcount/', 'plugin.js');
    CKEDITOR.replace('body', {
        extraPlugins: 'wordcount',
        customConfig: '/assets/js/ckeditor/config.js'
    });
</script>
```

ON MY SITE I have the wordcount plugin hosted at (take a guess)

```
mydomain.com/assets/ckeditor/plugins/wordcount/plugin.js
```

The error I get:

> GET http://cdn.ckeditor.com/404.shtml/ net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
>   Uncaught Error: [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name "notification" was not found at "http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.8/standard/plugins/notification/plugin.js?t=G2VC"

Answer (score 2):

According to their documentation at https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ the "standard" preset doesn't include any other plugin, you must switch the path to "standard-all" so the rest of the plugins are present.

For me this is a bug on their side as I fail to see any advantage to use "standard" over "standard-all" if the files that are loaded in both situations are the same, but with the disadvantage that it will fail if you try to use any other plugin.